# Rails nested resource not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have two forms (Clients and Posts).

- For my client, I can create/show/update/delete my client with no problem.
- For my post, I can create/show and delete. But for some reason it does not update.
  In the update form, after I make the changes and click on the "Update Post" button, it shows as if it was updated, but when I check the post, it still has the old data. I do not know what could be wrong.

Here is part of my code:

My client.rb

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many:posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

My client controller

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :find_client, only:[:show, :edit, :update]
... is working fine
```

My post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :find_client
before_action :find_post, only:[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
    @posts = @client.posts
end

def new
    @post = @client.posts.new
end
def create
    @post = @client.posts.create(post_param)
    flash[:notice]="Post Created Sucessfully."
    redirect_to client_post_path(@client, @post)
end

def update
    # @post = @client.posts.find(params[:id])
    if @post.save
        flash[:notice]="Post Updated Sucessfully"
        redirect_to client_post_path(@client, @post)
      else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post.destroy
    flash[:notice]="Post Deleted Sucessfully"
    redirect_to client_posts_path(@client)

end

private

def find_client
    @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
end

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def post_param
    params.require(:post).permit(:post_name, :title, :body)
end
end
```

My 'index.html.erb' for my posts

```
<h2>Posts of <%=@client.name%></h2>
<div class="NewItem">
<p><%= link_to "NEW POST", new_client_post_path(@client)%></p>
</div>
<div class="ListPosts">
<table border="1">    
    <th><td><b>Post Name</b></td><td><b>Post Title</b></td></th>
    <% @client.posts.each do |p|%>
        <tr>
            <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_client_post_path(@client,p) %> |      <%=link_to "Delete", [@client, p], method: :delete, data:{Confirm: "Confirm Data Exclusion?"}%></td>
            <td><%=p.post_name%></td>
            <td><%=p.title%></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
</div>
```

My partial '_editform.html.erb'

```
<h2>Edit Post of <%=@client.name%></h2>
<%= form_for [@client, @post] do |f|%>
<%=f.label:post_name %><br>
<%=f.text_field:post_name %><br>

<%=f.label:title %><br>
<%=f.text_field:title %><br>

<%=f.label:body %><br>
<%=f.text_area:body %><br>

<%=f.submit %><br>
<% end %>
```

My 'edit.html.erb'

```
<%= render 'editform'%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update action in your post controller didn't pass in the new submitted params to save. You need to pass in the new params like

```
def update
  @post = @client.posts.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update(post_params)
    flash[:notice]="Post Updated Sucessfully"
    redirect_to client_post_path(@client, @post)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post_name, :title, :body)
end
```

something like this, so you can update your post.